# unable to install specific libraries in Python

Tags: python, pip, gevent, python-wheel

I am trying to install gevent with pip but failed to install it.

```
Requirement already satisfied: gevent in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.11.5; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython" in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from gevent) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.13; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from gevent) (0.4.13)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.11.5; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"->gevent) (2.18)
tweepy 3.6.0 has requirement requests>=2.11.1, but you'll have requests 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
```

Please help me out with this error.

Comment: Installing `gevent` succeeded. It looks like you have some other problem, installing `tweepy`. Presumably some other package you haven't shown us here demands requests == or <= 2.10.0, but we can't diagnose that without knowing what you have installed, or at least what happens when you try to upgrade `requests`. But at any rate, you can't ask about a problem you don't actually have in hopes of getting an answer to a different problem you haven't explained.

Comment: No,  it is not installed. I know it is saying that the requirement already satisfied but when I run the script I get "    from gevent import monkey
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gevent' ".

Comment: The error shows that you need ot upgrade `requests` to satisfy `tweepy`'s requirements. Also as an advice, when working multiple python projects, it would be best to use `virtualenv`

Comment: Ohh. @Damian you're working with windows right? were you able to include python in your Environment Variables?

Comment: I didn't know about the `virtualenv`. But right now how do I update `tweepy`?

Comment: @VincentPakson I have already included the Python in my Environment Variable.

Comment: now Im a bit confused? are you trying to install gevent or tweepy? or are you trying to install tweepy but cant instlall it cause gevent is a requirement and you cant install it? it seems that you already have though. just upgrade the requests.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows requests package version is not incompatible.
so, how about update requests with command:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs while installing tweepy. The error says:

```
tweepy 3.6.0 has requirement requests>=2.11.1, but you'll have requests 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
```

So, you need to upgrade requests.

For linux, to install:

```
pip install requests
```

For linux, to upgrade:

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

Hope that helps